# child content hidden after applying shadow IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

i have this following [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zofuj/1/)

HTML view

```
    <div id="main">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dEM0KGG.png" id="image">
      <div id="secd">
       <iframe src='http://www.hdfcbank.com' height='350' width='350' frameborder='0'       border='0' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>
     </div>
     </div>
```

am applying shadow to main container as follows

```
     $('#main').css('filter','progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#aaaaaa,direction=27    
0,strength=10)'+'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#aaaaaa,direction=180,strength=10)');
```

After applying i notice that div id #secd content is hidden.
how i can solve this.

Let me know if have gone wrong somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browser you use, the iframe will have a different z-index.  For example, in older versions of IE (I think back to IE7) the iframe had the highest z-index and would even appear on top of select boxes.  However, Microsoft has since fixed this.

In this case, the iframe is nested inside of the div with id="main"

Try to use a css3 box-shadow instead if you can ... usage example:

```
#main{
  background-color:#ffffff;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

You can also use this link to help you create the perfect drop shadow using a box-shadow:

http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/

Assuming you are running the latest version of IE and you using the debugger tool to simulate an older version of IE, ensure that you have filters activated in the browser.  For examples of how to accomplish this please read the following directions:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801215(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: So applying z-index to iframe or div will fix this issue ? but if i dont apply shadow then iframe can be seen

Comment: what are our browser targets?  I would recommend using the css3 box-shadow property rather than the IE dependent filtet.  Box-shadow will work in  IE9+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari 5.1.1.

Comment: yes i am using css3 box shadow for IE 9 + and others. wanted to make it work on IE 8 also

Answer (score 0):

I believe using pie.js will solve almost issues related to CSS3 and its easy to use as well. Please add the below line of code inside your head tag.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="yourpath/pie.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

and then add all  your codes into js as shown below:

```
$(function() {
  if (window.PIE) {
    $('.rounded').each(function() {
        PIE.attach(this);
    });
   }
});
```

Few more links: http://css3pie.com/download/

http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/

Comment: cant i use only filters and make it work instead of using an external library.

Comment: hi, this is really scalable approach. Nevertheless, if you want to go ahead with pure css then you may like this one. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/.
PS: I just googled to get this for u bcz so far i found pie suffice my projects for IE8.

Comment: hey i tried css3pie but couldnt get the box shadow work.
followed exactly how they gave in documentation. is it  the problem with loading of .htc file?

Comment: Try with .js version. But just a suggestion put it under IE conditional code. <!--[if IE 8]><script... /><![endif]-->